# Why GenericObjectPool.addObject throws checked Exception

Tags: java, apache-commons

Is there any any good reason why Apache's (useful) org.apache.commons.pool.impl.commmons.pool.GenericObjectPool.addObject() is declared to throw Exception?

Actually, org.apache.commons.pool.BaseObjectPool declares it as such, from the org.apache.commons.pool interface:

```
/**
 * Create an object using the {@link PoolableObjectFactory factory} or other
 * implementation dependent mechanism, passivate it, and then place it in the idle object pool.
 * <code>addObject</code> is useful for "pre-loading" a pool with idle objects.
 * (Optional operation).
 *
 * @throws Exception when {@link PoolableObjectFactory#makeObject} fails.
 * @throws IllegalStateException after {@link #close} has been called on this pool.
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException when this pool cannot add new idle objects.
 */
void addObject() throws Exception, IllegalStateException, UnsupportedOperationException;
```

Why not some derivative of RuntimeException?

```
/**
 * Create an object, and place it into the pool.
 * addObject() is useful for "pre-loading" a pool with idle objects.
 */
@Override
public void addObject() throws Exception {
    assertOpen();
    if (_factory == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot add objects without a factory.");
    }
    T obj = _factory.makeObject();
    try {
        assertOpen();
        addObjectToPool(obj, false);
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) { // Pool closed
        try {
            _factory.destroyObject(obj);
        } catch (Exception ex2) {
            // swallow
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need, at the very least, to trace the calls like: addObjectToPool and destroyObject to see if one or more of them is throwing Exception.  As for why?  Who knows... but throwing a RuntimeException isn't a good idea either.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the direct answer is right there in the Javadoc:

```
@throws Exception when {@link PoolableObjectFactory#makeObject} fails.
```

(aside: the factory interface seems to actually be `PooledObjectFactory`, not `Poolable`)

So, why does makeObject throw Exception?  A common use case for object pools is to pool database connections, which are expensive to create and destroy and are (were?) sometimes restricted by software licensing (an N-connection license).  Creating a new database connection may throw SQLException, or perhaps IOException if the database server is on a remote machine.  makeObject is declared to throw Exception so these checked exceptions can be passed through and caught when trying to put/retrive a connection to/from the pool.